# Can't open mongo shell in Terminal or when trying to start express.js server

Tags: mongodb, express, command-line-interface, mongo-shell

I am trying to use express.js to create a API server for a project I want to build using MongoDB. But when I attempt to run `mongosh` in the terminal to check and clean up old databases I get this error message in the terminal image below, I am having difficulties trouble shooting.

[image: Attempt to open Mongo shell]

I have ran `mongod` too but I am not sure if this was successful in starting the local servers.

[image: Running mongod + response]

I've used express before for a previous project that has been deployed on mongoDB so I was not expecting to run into this issue.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Answer (score 0):

I had to start mongodb-community with:

`brew services start mongodb-community`